# stop all existing spark contexts

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a new Spark context using pyspark, and i get the following:

> WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw
>   an exception in its constructor).  This may indicate an error, since
>   only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The
>   other SparkContext was created at:
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)

I do not have any other context active (in theory), but maybe it did not finish correctly and it is still there. How can I find out if there is other or kill all the current ones? I am using spark 1.5.1

Comment: You can try killing or restarting your Python kernel.

Comment: Hi @apeleteiro any solution to this? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

When you run pyspark shell and execute python script inside it, e.g., using 'execfile()', SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext. To run a python script without any contexts just use ./bin/spark-submit 'your_python_file'.